# Getting a SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in PHP Apache Docker container using mariadb, if connected via Dockerfile's CMD (PHP CLI works)

Tags: mysql, apache-2.4, docker, mariadb, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a Docker container based on:

- PHP 8.1
- Apache 2.4
- MariaDB (latest official docker image)

It all starts up without any issue; but I'm unable to connect with the Docker Container's DB via PDO.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && apt update \
    && apt install libzip-dev -y \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY composer.json .

RUN groupadd -r user && useradd -r -g user user
USER user
RUN composer install --no-dev

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["php","src/init.php"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:

  php:
    build: ./php
    depends_on:
      - db
      - adminer
    container_name: php-apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      # setup xdebug to be able to use PHP step debugger, if needed
      - ./php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
      - ./php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
      # apache config (server name)
      - ./apache/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
      # apache config (rewrite rule to reroute all requests to unknown resources through to REST controller)
      - ./apache/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
      # Source code
      - ./php/src:/var/www/html/src
      # unbind local composer components
      - /php/vendor
      - /php/composer.lock
      - /php/composer.phar
    environment:
      MARIADB_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
      MARIADB_USER: root
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: top_very_secret
      MARIADB_DB: apidb

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - maria-db-storage:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: top_very_secret
      MARIADB_DATABASE: apidb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

volumes:
  maria-db-storage:
```

According to the majority of the posts and answers from different forums, I've tried to use both `localhost` as well as `127.0.0.1` as the value of the environment variable `MARIADB_HOST` (and besides, I'm inerested in knowing why that should be supposed to work?). Anyway, it does not solve the problem, the following php code (content of `src/init.php`):

```
new PDO(
    "mysql:host={$_ENV['MARIADB_HOST']};dbname={$_ENV['MARIADB_DB']}",
    $_ENV['MARIADB_USER'],
    $_ENV['MARIADB_PASSWORD'],
    [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]
);
```

Always results in:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.

**UPDATE**

I came a step further by replacing this line here:

`MARIADB_HOST: "127.0.0.1"`

with the name of my database service; being:

`MARIADB_HOST: db`

I found this out because I found out at the same time that I can only login to the adminer dashboard if I use `db` as the host. Hence this was rather a guess, and I would still love to understand why this works now..?

This however still does not fully work yet. It only works if I omit the `CMD` line in the dockerfile, build the container, migrate into its terminal via `docker exec -t -i php-apache /bin/bash`, and run the command `php src/init.php` from within there. If I try to do so via `CMD` form the `Dockerfile` (as detailed above), I get the mentioned error. What am I still missing? I would of course prefer to automate this init call with the running start of the Docker container. Digging further...

Answer (score 0):

Got it for real now. The connection was refused because the environment variables were only used if the script is executed via shell, and via Docker's `CMD` - as I used it - no shell processing occurred. From the docs, I also found [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker.

> When used in the shell or exec formats, the CMD instruction sets the
> command to be executed when running the image.

> If you use the shell form of the CMD, then the  will execute
> in /bin/sh -c

Using:

`CMD [ "sh", "-c", "php src/init.php" ]`

instead of:

`CMD [ "php", "src/init.php" ]`

Did the job!